# Is there a Git command to import a hg repository

Tags: git, mercurial

With `git svn clone` I can work on a subversion repository using git. Is there a similar way to work on Mercurial (hg) repositories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git interoperability with a Mercurial Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository)

Comment: Title is closer match to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389307/convert-a-mercurial-repository-to-git

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't anything built in.

You can use [`git-hg`](https://github.com/offbytwo/git-hg) however, which I use a lot and works great for pulling hg repos and updates to a git repo, but the downside of it is that you cannot push updates made to your git repo to a hg repo with `git-hg`.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Only pulling will probably work for me, since I was just interested in looking at source code for Mockito (which is in Mercurial)

Comment: This answer is out of date. [A bridge](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/) is now integrated in Git, and works fine

Comment: @CharlesB +1 and thanks for this hint.  It comes with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Debian wheezy-backports these days, but is not active by default.  Look into `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/remote-helpers/` for the scripts to copy them somewhere into `$PATH`

Answer (score 3):

The Mercurial extension `hg-git` is another way to go in the Hg->Git direction. If you just want to go in that direction, so far as I can see, it and `git-hg` both work well. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository/11178693#11178693).

Comment: What does this answer add beyond erikvold's answer? A comment would suffice for a link.

Answer (score 0):

If it was the other case, I mean if you need a git->hg conversion you can use mercurial's [Convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension). But for your question [git-hg](https://github.com/offbytwo/git-hg) should do fine.

Comment: Wrong question. Check the timestamp of mine and erikvold's answer.

Comment: My mistake! Unfortunately, I can't change it now.