# Contributing patches from Mercurial to Git?

Tags: git, mercurial, repository

I'd like to fork a Git repository, convert it to Mercurial, and contribute my changes back to the original Git repository when I'm done. I am more concerned with a safe and stable conversion process than its convenience. I will be `pull`ing changes from Git into Mercurial on a regular basis but rarely contributing any changes back.

I'm not comfortable using [hg-git](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git) because many of the bugs reported against the project have gone unanswered for years. I suspect it's safer to use `hg convert` to convert Git to Hg than using `hg-git`.

My question is: say I've already converted the repository to Mercurial and made some changes, **how do I contribute these changes back to the official repository?** I'd like to contribute my changes back to the official Git repository without losing any history information (that is, I don't want to fold multiple changesets into a one).

What is the easiest and safest way to do this?

Comment: There are reasons to use a modern scm when a project is officially hosted on something like svn or cvs, thus the wide availability of tools to make that easy. But if the project is already hosted in a modern scm then there's a lot less reason not to just use the same scm locally.

Comment: @bames53, I agree but like many other decisions we make on a daily basis, this one is purely subjective :)

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that link isn't to the official hg-git repo?  That can be found [here](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git).

Comment: @obmarg, according to http://hg-git.github.com/ the link you provided is actually a mirror of the link I provided (which is the canonical source). See the links at the bottom of the website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try and export your Mercurial commits as patches:

```
hg export --git -r 1 >patch.diff
```

This `.diff` file should be recognized by Git and could be added to the git repo with [`git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply.html).
(This was suggested in "[Convert a Mercurial Repository to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389307/convert-a-mercurial-repository-to-git)", where the more up-to-date [script `hg-fast-export`](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git) was also mentioned)

The `--git` option of [`hg export`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#export) will make sure you generate diffs in the git extended diff format. See [`hg help diffs`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#diffs) for more information.

Comment: Won't this collapse multiple changesets into one?

Comment: @Gili: if that is so, you would simply list all the Hg revisions you are interested in and, for each one, produce a `.diff` file (that you would apply in turn to your Git repo). `hg export` can take a single revision or a range of revision.

Comment: I ran a quick test: `hg export --git -r 1 -r 2 >patch.diff` embeds both revisions into the same file but provides sufficient information for which changes go into which changeset. I believe this will work. Thanks!

Comment: git does not accept such patches, says "error: unrecognized input"

Comment: @Alex Strange: what git version re you using? On which OS? Which git command did you use? Is there some eol issue? (\r\n applied to a \n file)

Comment: I opened the generated patch in a text editor and saved it as utf-8 without BOM, then git was able to read the patch. But unfortunately it accused other problems down the road. I don't remember exactly the error message, but other people suggested that git has problems with patches with binary files (at least with hg-generated patches with binary files)

Comment: @Alex That would explain the other problem indeed: I tested it with pure text diff, no binary involved.