# How can I convert a Mercurial repository to Git...in *Windows*?

Tags: git, mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a Mercurial (hg) repository to Git on Windows (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267232/converting-a-mercurial-hg-repository-to-git-on-windows-7)

There's a Mercurial repository that I want to convert to Git, which is what we use at work.  I have Mercurial (for Windows) installed, and I've already cloned the Hg repository locally.  I'm stuck on trying to convert it.

Most of the pages I've found assume that I'm using Unix/Linux, and the most common recommendation, hg-fast-export, seems to work only in those OSes.  I do have access to the Git Bash.  I've gotten as far as this (line-wrapped for easier reading):

```
$ ~/codeingit/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r
        ~/codeinmercurial/projectiwanttoconvert
```

In response, I get:

> ImportError: No module named mercurial

I've read a number of web pages about this which, again, assume that I'm using Unix/Linux and that I have Mercurial installed for that.

Is there anyone who's successfully converted an Hg repository to Git on **Windows**, and can write a step-by-step guide to doing it?

Comment: Technically, there's always the classic 3-step solution that works in cases like this: 1) get VMWare-Player, 2) get a Linux-distribution of your choice, 3) follow the Linux-based guides :-)

Comment: @cpeisert, I saw that one, but there's not anywhere near enough detail for me to be able to do what I want to do, unless cygwin actually includes mercurial, python, etc. out of the box.  Does it?

Comment: @Kyralessa, Yes, the Cygwin [packages](http://cygwin.com/packages/) include [mercurial](http://cygwin.com/packages/mercurial/), [python](http://cygwin.com/packages/python/), and [git](http://cygwin.com/packages/git/) out of the box as well as anything else you may need.

Comment: @cpeisert, that's a pageful of stuff I don't know what to do with.  Pretend I know nothing about Linux/Unix, and don't want to learn it all today, but just want to get this task done.  What would I do, step by step?  I don't mind installing stuff if it helps me get the task done.

Comment: @Kyralessa, See answer below, which I tested on Windows 7 with a clean Cygwin install.

Comment: @George Stocker, if that question had helped, I wouldn't have opened this one.

Answer (score 42):

### 1) [Install Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) or [Bash on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

**Cygwin**

- Run [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/install.html)
- Select *Install from Internet*
- In the **Select Packages** dialog box:

  - Click *Install* at the top of the tree (next to *All*) until it shows *Default*
  - Expand the ***Devel*** subtree: Install *git* (change from *Skip* to the version number)
  - In the ***Devel*** subtree: Install *mercurial* (change from *Skip* to the version number)
  - Install ***Python*** subtree (change from *Default* to *Install*)
  - Click Next
- If prompted to resolve dependencies, click Next
- Get a cup of coffee, watch your favorite movie, or take a long nap

After the Cygwin installation is complete, open a bash shell to run the commands indicated in the steps below. The shortcut to bash will be called ***Cygwin Terminal***.

**Windows 10**

- [Install Bash on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)
- Get a cup of coffee
- Open Bash and type the following:

  - sudo apt install git
  - sudo apt install mercurial

### 2) Install [fast-export](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git/)

Open terminal (bash shell) and install *fast-export*:

```
   https://github.com/frej/fast-export.git
```

### 3) Initialize new git repo and migrate mercurial repo

```
   mkdir new_git_repo
   cd new_git_repo
   git init
   ../fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo
   git checkout HEAD
```

**Potential Error**

```
fatal: Invalid raw date "<devnull@localhost> xxx -xxxx" in ident:  <><devnull@localhost> xxx -xxxx
```

Try adding an "authors.txt" file as described [here](https://github.com/frej/fast-export/issues/15), containing:

```
<>=devnull <devnull@localhost>
```

The command line now reads:

```
../fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /path/to/old/mercurial_repo -A ../fast-export/authors
```

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't had time at work to try this yet, but I will respond when I have time in the next week or two to try it out.

Comment: after trying numerous other "fast"-export tutorials, this one did it.

Comment: To anyone trying to convert from Mercurial to Git (on Windows)-- this is the best way. It might seem like overkill -- it is not. Save yourself a lot of headache, and follow these steps.

Comment: Note that if you had cloned `fast-export` from git for windows, the shell script “hg-fast-export.sh” might have Windows line endings (CR-LF) in which case the script won't run properly.

Comment: For those of you who aren't comfortable with the repo at the .cz domain, you can use `https://github.com/frej/fast-export` instead (thanks to comments at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6917665/284598).

Comment: to solve encoding problem with hg-fast-export you can use '-e' and '--fe' options 
(in my case by default comments imported well, but file names not: '--fe cp1251' solve this)

Comment: I spent hours trying numerous recommended approaches, including Cygwin. With Cygwin I ran into Python issues. Many of the approaches were based on older versions of Mercurial, Python, Git, etc.

What finally worked for me quick and easy was following the simple directions from Lorenzo Mori in http://www.lorenzomori.com/programming/convert-your-mercurial-repository-to-git-on-windows