# Error converting Hg repo to Git: 'no match found'

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

I'm trying to follow various [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389307/convert-a-mercurial-repository-to-git/17429713#17429713) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267232/converting-a-mercurial-hg-repository-to-git-on-windows-7/30647018#30647018) for converting `.hg` to `.git`. When I run

```
hg gexport --debug
```

I get an error on a revision saying

> abort: data/web/Server/Properties/PublishProfiles/Web Deploy.pubxml@842a35fd10b511e515bfdf83c67300102000a187: no match found

What does this mean and what can I do about it?

I remember on that commit I had some trouble because I think I deleted the .xml file in some wrong way and needed to add it then commit then delete then commit again and that was the only way I could push.

Comment: `hg verify` and see https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption for more     information about recovery from corruption of the repository.

Comment: `hg verify` says there are 2 integrity errors encountered. Both related to the same file `hg gexport` was encountering. The first changeset where it's encountered is where that `.xml` file was added for the first time. When I look at that changeset in TortiseHg and select that file it says `File or diffs not displayed: data/web/Server/Properties/PublishProfiles/Web Deploy.pubxml@842a35fd10b511e515bfdf83c67300102000a187: no match found` in the diffs windows. That was almost 3 years and 1200 commits ago.

Comment: I should have added the error message from `hg verify`, too: `manifest refers to unknown revision`. I don't see at lot of info about that error message around.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned from a different remote and it all worked.

Comment: This corroborates that the first remote probably had internal corruption.